# Detect Keystrokes Out of Window C++

Tags: c++, windows

I've been working on a simple program that will run a loop when a key is pressed, and will end the loop when the same, (or another) key is pressed, but will not end the program. I have tried to use the _getch() function, and it's helped me detect the keystroke, but I need a way to detect a keystroke out of the console window. For example, if I was playing a video game, and I hit a key, I need the loop to run until I hit the key again or a different key. Thanks!

Comment: What operating system are you working with or targeting?

Comment: There is nothing in C++ that lets you detect keystrokes or deal with windows. You need to use your platform API.

Comment: I'm working with the windows 10 operating system.

Comment: How would I go about using the Platform API?

Comment: There's a number of operating-system specific APIs for this. Windowed applications work differently from command-line ones though.

Comment: @tadman Where could I find the Platform API?

Comment: Stop one is *always* [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645530(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Stack Overflow is all about doing your homework, writing code, and then when that code has problems, sharing your code and doing your best to describe those problems in ways that people can help you resolve them. I'd suggest amending your question with actual code that you've tried.

Comment: @tadman Alright, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

GetKeyState/GetAsyncKeyState. Search them on MSDN. Both will work for the required task. Basically, they inspect the current state of the key. Loop through the keys you need current state of. For event-based handling, use SetWindowsHookEx - it is actually better, but harder to implement. For both methods I've described there are a lot of information on the web.